# Bootstrap 3 site not behaving in IE8 and under

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

Cannot figure why the site I'm building looks/behaves incorrectly in IE8
Testing site:
http://ite.bluenotion.com/zagdotcom/

Header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700|Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific.. nobody here is going to find out what exactly is wrong with your site just by checking it..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't work with IE8 out of the box. To make sure that `@media` queries work in IE8 use this script:

https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

css3-mediaqueries.js by Wouter van der Graaf is a JavaScript library to make IE 5+, Firefox 1+ and Safari 2 transparently parse, test and apply CSS3 Media Queries. Firefox 3.5+, Opera 7+, Safari 3+ and Chrome already offer native support.

This works for my BS3 sites :)

Comment: To clarify, [Bootstrap officially supports IE8](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support), although yes, it requires you to add the html5shiv and Respond.js. Theoretically, using a different media query polyfill in place of Respond.js should also work.

Comment: Thanks! Strange though, as I'm already loading html5shiv and repsond.js

I'll try using css3 mediaqueries though.

Comment: Can you tell me what is displaying "incorrect"? A screenshot would be good (I don't have IE here).

Comment: So, you run both html5shiv/respond.js AND this? I'm having similar issues. My nav still doesn't work even with html5shiv and respond.js